# glossaries - renewing \glossaryentryfield and \glossarysubentryfield

Tags: glossaries

I noticed that after updating glossaries today, I had an error related to  `\renewcommand*{\glossarysubentryfield}{...}` and
`\renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}{...}`: the commands weren't previously defined. This makes me wonder, are these commands obsolete--I can't find them in the manual? What should I use instead, and what else is wrong with my two-column style list of acronyms? It still seems to work okay, except that page numbers (unwantingly) appear after the update.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries} \makeglossaries
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newglossarystyle{AcronymsTwoCol}{%
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}%
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%
    \renewcommand*{\glossarysubentryfield}[6]{glssubentryitem{##2}{\strut\glstarget{##2}##4\glspostdescription\space ##6}}% caused error on update 2022-10-14, must be newcommand now ?
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{\vspace{7pt}}% space between alphabetized groups
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
        {\vspace*{1ex}\setlength{\columnsep}{30pt}\begin{multicols}{2}%
        \begin{description}[font=\bfseries,leftmargin=1.7cm,style=multiline,itemsep=3pt]}%
        {\end{description}\end{multicols}}%
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{% also must be newcommand now...
        \item[{\normalfont\bfseries\glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{##2}}]{##3\glspostdescription}  %
        }%
}

\newacronym{abc}{ABC}{A's, B's, and C's}
\newacronym{fb}{FB}{Foo Bar}
\newacronym{xyz}{XYZ}{Xamine Your Zipper}

\begin{document}
\gls{abc}\gls{fb}\gls{xyz}

Hello.
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=AcronymsTwoCol]


\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\usepackage{glossaries}[=v4.46]`

Comment: That's the older version, right? How would I go about achieving what I want with the newest version?